# NSObject custom init with object/parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

What i'm trying to accomplish is something like

```
Person *person1 = [[Person alloc]initWithDict:dict];
```

and then in the `NSObject` "Person", have something like:

```
-(void)initWithDict:(NSDictionary*)dict{
    self.name = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
    self.age = [dict objectForKey:@"Age"];
    return (Person with name and age);
}
```

which then allows me to keep using the person object with those params. Is this possible, or do I have to do the normal

```
Person *person1 = [[Person alloc]init];
person1.name = @"Bob";
person1.age = @"123";
```

?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your return type is void while it should `instancetype`.

And you can use both type of code which you want....

Update:

```
@interface testobj : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSDictionary *data;

-(instancetype)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation testobj
@synthesize data;

-(instancetype)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict{
self = [super init];
if(self)
{
   self.data = dict;
}
return self;
}

@end
```

Use it as below:

```
    testobj *tt = [[testobj alloc] initWithDict:@{ @"key": @"value" }];
NSLog(@"%@",tt.ss);
```

Comment: That was an example, I don't know how to implement it properly. If you could post an demo .h and .m, that would be of great help.

Answer (score 10):

change your code like this

```
-(id)initWithDict:(NSDictionary*)dict
 {
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {       
      self.name = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
      self.age = [dict objectForKey:@"Age"];
    }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: Good answer but it would be even better if also give some information (or just links) as to why it is better.

Comment: @Monolo :) My English is not very good, too complex sentences, may make people don't understand~~

Comment: this answer is more clear and self-explained :), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So you can use modern objective-c style to get associative array values ;)

```
-(id)initWithDict:(NSDictionary*)dict
 {
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {       
      self.name = dict[@"Name"];
      self.age = dict[@"Age"];
    }
   return self;
}
```